# How might I use letrec in this function so that it does the same job as it does with named let?

Tags: scheme, racket, let

I've [read here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html) that named `let` can be rewritten with `letrec`.
And so I proceeded to rewrite the following function with `letrec`:

```
(define (duplicate pos lst)
  (let dup ([i 0] [lst lst])
   (cond
     [(= i pos) (cons (car lst) lst)]
     [else (cons (car lst) (dup (+ i 1) (cdr lst)))])))
```

My attempt at this:

```
(define (duplicate pos lst)
  (letrec ((dup (lambda ([i 0] [lst lst])
     (cond
       [(= i pos) (cons (car lst) lst)]
       [else (cons (car lst) (dup (+ i 1) (cdr lst)))]))))))
```

Sadly, when I call it with `(duplicate 1 (list "apple" "cheese burger!" "banana"))` I get from Racket `letrec: bad syntax (missing body)`. How might I rewrite `duplicate` with `letrec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the documentation for [`letrec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._letrec%29%29), it has these arguments:

`(letrec ([id val-expr] ...) body ...+)`

So, you have to add at least one `body` form after definitions.

I also replaced `cond` with [`if`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._if%29%29) (you have only two branches of code), `(+ ... 1)` with [`add1`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._add1%29%29) and improved indentation:

```
#lang racket

(define (duplicate pos lst)
  (letrec ((dup (lambda ([i 0] [lst lst])
                  (if (= i pos)
                      (cons (car lst)
                            lst)
                      (cons (car lst)
                            (dup (add1 i) (cdr lst)))))))
    (dup)))
```

Test:

```
> (duplicate 1 (list "apple" "cheese burger!" "banana"))
'("apple" "cheese burger!" "cheese burger!" "banana")
```

Answer (score 1):

The named let is (more or less) a locally defined regular procedure that is  called "behind the scenes".
The body of a named let is not the body of the equivalent "unnamed" let, but the body of that procedure;

```
(let f ([x init])
   body)
```

can be rewritten as

```
(letrec ([f (lambda ([x init]) body)])
    (f))
```

or, without using default arguments (which some would find clearer),

```
(letrec ([f (lambda (x) body)])
    (f init))
```